# Why can usermod not modify newly created user? "User does not exist"

Tags: centos, users, chroot, accounts

Please see the commands I have run trying to modify a user that was just created.

```
# useradd temp
# usermod -R /home/temp temp
usermod: user 'temp' does not exist
```

The above is odd, so I did a few things to confirm the user exists:

```
# su temp
$ whoami
temp
$ exit
# grep temp /etc/shadow
temp:!!:18292:0:99999:7:::
# grep temp /etc/group
temp:x:1002:
```

yet still:

```
# usermod -R /home/temp temp
usermod: user 'temp' does not exist
```

a different user mod command works though:

```
# usermod -s /sbin/nologin temp
#
```

(no complaints. change worked)

Why can I not chroot the new user?

Comment: Asking why one cannot `chroot` when the question makes no mention of that anywhere else, does not make for a good question.

Answer (score 0):

answer from `twofifths` on freenode `##linux`

because you're chrooting and the user isn't defined once inside of it